# How do you launch QGIS (Mac) without any plugins enabled?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, osx

On a Mac, how can you launch Qgis without any plugins enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-open a terminal and type:

```
/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS --noplugins
```

-and for qgis 3.x (version 3.6 shown here)

```
/Applications/QGIS3.6.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS --noplugins
```